# How to get a layer's type in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to select the last Conv2D layer for a given (general) model. `model.summary()` provides a list of layers with their type, but how can I access this to find the layer of that type?

Output from `model.summary()`:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
...
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 1000)              4097000   
=================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over `model.layers` in reverse order and check layer types via `isinstance`:

```
next(x for x in model.layers[::-1] if isinstance(x, keras.layers.Conv2D))
```

Answer (score 16):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
layer.__class__.__name__
```

where layer is in

`model.layers`